# MSAL JS loginPopup vs acquireTokenPop

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

What is the difference between [loginPopup](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/src/app/PublicClientApplication.ts#68) and `acquireTokenPopup` methods in [PublicClientApplication](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/src/app/PublicClientApplication.ts) class?

Internally `loginPopup` calls `acquireTokenPopup` and does not do anything else and wanted to know if these methods could be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that these methods can be used interchangeably, as they do the same thing under the hood. The main difference is that `acquireTokenPopup` requires scopes, while `loginPopup` does not (we set default scopes), which is done to maintain the API and usage semantics from MSAL.js v1.

Comment: Thanks Jason and to clarify, `PublicClientApplication` is v2 and `UserAgentClientApplication` is v1?